# Saving more then 1 models in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of ts values and i need to save all garch models (models construct for each column af a matrix) in a list. I tried this code and it doesn't work (i can't understand why):

```
model = list()
for (i in ncol(p)) {
  if (length(model) == 0) {
      model = list(ugarchfit(data=p[-1,i], spec=spec))
  } else {
      bufer = ugarchfit(data=p[-1,i], spec=spec)
      model = cbind(model, bufer)
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me to cope with this? I need to address this list with the column index and get a model for this column index.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with?

Comment: Do you just want one model for every column in `p`?

Comment: `for (i in seq_len(ncol(p))) {model[[i]] <- ugarchfit(data=p[-1,i],spec=spec)}`?

Answer (score 2):

It is better the create the list with final dimensions rather that to create a growing list.

```
models <- vector("list", ncol(p))
```

Then overwrite the relevant element of the list

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(p))) {
  models[[i]] <- ugarchfit(data = p[-1, i], spec = spec)
}
```

Another solution would to use lapply

```
models <- lapply(
  seq_len(ncol(p)),
  function(i) {
    ugarchfit(data = p[-1, i], spec = spec)
  }
)
```

Note that your code will be more clear is you use `=` for passing arguments to a function and `<-` for assignments.

Comment: `for (i in seq_len(ncol(p)))`